# Access Denied Error InputStream ENOENT/EACCES despite checking permission first

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to read in a file .xyz using

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"file.xyz");
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("file.xyz");
```

Moreover I used the following code to check my access rights:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
    System.out.println("EXTERNALSTORAGE_AVAILABLE = " + Boolean.toString(mExternalStorageAvailable));
    System.out.println("EXTERNALSTORAGE_WRITEABLE = " + Boolean.toString(mExternalStorageWriteable));
```

I get for both booleans the value FALSE. What is even more strange is when I use getPath() I get /mnt/sdcard. I do have a folder mnt but there is no sdcard inside. I also used ls -a to show hidden folders, but there is nothing. However, when I use `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"` and then `dir.exists()` I get TRUE!? However it doesnt work and I get the error message EACCES (although I do either see a folder sdcard nor a file file.xyz when I go into the folder mnt...So I thought okay then lets put it in another directory on my Linux Debian system (without sudo rights btw). So I did the following:

```
File file = new File("/folder1/folder2/.../","file.xyz");
```

But then I clearly see the directory and put the file in it but I get FALSE for `dir.exists()`. And the error is ENOENT.

Moreover I put the permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

Into my AndroidManifest.xml.

Btw (maybe this is of importance) when is use

```
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        System.out.println("STORAGESTATE equal MEDIA_MOUNTED");
    } else{
        System.out.println("STORAGESTATE NOT equal MEDIA_MOUNTED");
    }
```

I get STORAGESTATE NOT equal MEDIA_MOUNTED.

Thanks for your help!
Best,
BootTooth

Comment: You seem to be mixing up three entirely different types of storage - assets, external storage, and folders on your development machine (which are not accessable to the device at all).  The android device (real or emulated) is its own computer, entitely distinct.

Comment: @ChrisStratton RIGHT! Now I got it. Thanks. For further helps how to proceed I appreciate. I mean why can I not take a file from my Eclipse_Projects folder? My file.xyz is there. So should I not access that one? Where is my virtual external Android storage? But you made clear my main issue with it. Thanks again...

Comment: If I got it correctly I have to make a new SDCard and mount that with a usual folder in such that I can insert my files there and finally unmount to run the emulator. (As here http://www.jayway.com/2009/04/22/working-with-sd-cards-in-the-android-emulator/)
However since I do NOT have sudo rights I can not mount my folder?

Comment: The Problem was that one has to explicitly add an SD card when starting the emulator! Thanks.